# Spin Connection using Mathematica

Tags: physics, tensors

Hello I want to use Mathematica in order to calculate the spin connection of a metric, specifically of the metric 
\begin{equation}
\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
-1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \frac{1-K\left(y^{2}+z^{2}\right)}{1-K\left(x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}\right)} & \frac{K x y}{1-K\left(x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}\right)} & \frac{K x z}{1-K\left(x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}\right)} \\
0 & \frac{K x y}{1-K\left(x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}\right)} & \frac{1-K\left(x^{2}+z^{2}\right)}{1-K\left(x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}\right)} & \frac{K y z}{1-K\left(x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}\right)} \\
0 & \frac{K x z}{1-K\left(x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}\right)} & \frac{K y z}{1-K\left(x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}\right)} & \frac{1-K\left(x^{2}+y^{2}\right)}{1-K\left(x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}\right)}
\end{array}\right)
\end{equation}
I have calculated the Christoffel Symbols as follows,

```
coord = {t, x, y, z}
n = 4
metric = {{-1, 0, 0, 
   0}, {0, (1 - K*(y^2 + z^2))/(1 - K*(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)), 
   K*x*y/(1 - K*(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)), 
   K*x*z/(1 - K*(x^2 + y^2 + z^2))}, {0, 
   K*x*y/(1 - K*(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)), (1 - K*(x^2 + z^2))/(1 - 
      K*(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)), K*y*z/(1 - K*(x^2 + y^2 + z^2))}, {0, 
   K*x*z/(1 - K*(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)), 
   K*y*z/(1 - K*(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)), (1 - K*(x^2 + y^2))/(1 - 
      K*(x^2 + y^2 + z^2))}}
inversemetric = Simplify[Inverse[metric]]
affine := affine = Simplify[Table[(1/2)*Sum[(inversemetric[[i, s]])*
       (D[metric[[s, j]], coord[[k]] ] +
         D[metric[[s, k]], coord[[j]] ] - 
         D[metric[[j, k]], coord[[s]] ]), {s, 1, n}],
    {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}, {k, 1, n}] ]
listaffine := 
 Table[If[UnsameQ[affine[[i, j, k]], 
    0], {ToString[\[CapitalGamma][i, j, k]], affine[[i, j, k]]}] , {i,
    1, n}, {j, 1, n}, {k, 1, j}]
TableForm[Partition[DeleteCases[Flatten[listaffine], Null], 2], 
 TableSpacing -> {2, 2}]
```

I will be using the following definition for the spin connection 
\begin{equation}
\omega_{\mu b}^{a}=e_{\nu}^{a} e_{b}^{\sigma} \Gamma_{\sigma \mu}^{\nu}+e_{\nu}^{a} \partial_{\mu} e_{b}^{\nu}
\end{equation}
where $=e_{\nu}^{a}$ is the vierbein (tetrad) and $e_{b}^{\sigma}$ is the inverse vierbein. I have tried the following

```
e = {{1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, (
  y^2 + z^2 + x^2 Sqrt[1/(1 - K (x^2 + y^2 + z^2))])/(
  x^2 + y^2 + z^2), (x y (-1 + Sqrt[1/(1 - K (x^2 + y^2 + z^2))]))/(
  x^2 + y^2 + z^2), (x z (-1 + Sqrt[1/(1 - K (x^2 + y^2 + z^2))]))/(
  x^2 + y^2 + z^2)}, {0, (
  x y (-1 + Sqrt[1/(1 - K (x^2 + y^2 + z^2))]))/(x^2 + y^2 + z^2), (
  x^2 + z^2 + y^2 Sqrt[1/(1 - K (x^2 + y^2 + z^2))])/(
  x^2 + y^2 + z^2), (y z (-1 + Sqrt[1/(1 - K (x^2 + y^2 + z^2))]))/(
  x^2 + y^2 + z^2)}, {0, (
  x z (-1 + Sqrt[1/(1 - K (x^2 + y^2 + z^2))]))/(x^2 + y^2 + z^2), (
  y z (-1 + Sqrt[1/(1 - K (x^2 + y^2 + z^2))]))/(x^2 + y^2 + z^2), (
  x^2 + y^2 + z^2 Sqrt[1/(1 - K (x^2 + y^2 + z^2))])/(
  x^2 + y^2 + z^2)}};
dete = Det[e];
inve = Simplify[Inverse[e]];
detinve = Det[inve];
Omega := Omega = 
  Simplify[Table[
    Sum[(e[[i, a]]*inve[[j, b]]*affine[[i, k, j]]) + 
      e[[i, a]]*D[inve[[i, b]], coord[[k]]], {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, 
      n}], {k, 1, n}, {a, 1, n}, {b, 1, n}]]
listOmega := 
 Table[If[UnsameQ[Omega[[k, a, b]], 
    0], {ToString[\[CapitalOmega][k, a, b]], Omega[[k, a, b]]}], {k, 
   1, n}, {a, 1, n}, {b, 1, n}]
TableForm[Partition[DeleteCases[Flatten[listOmega], Null], 2], 
 TableSpacing -> {2, 2}]
```

But unfortunately, I get very long solutions and such should not be the case. I would really appreciate if I could get some assistance in this matter, as I am fairly new to Mathematica and don't quite truly understand its workings. One last thing, my question is regarding the vierbein. Does it matter that $e_{\nu}^{a}$ has a contravariant and covariant index, as in does Mathematica know that it is taking a sum as the one of the formula? Or does it suffice to simply define it as a matrix and take a sum over the corresponding indices? Thank you in advance

[image: Definition of Spin Connection]

Comment: Add the code for the metric tensor and for tetrad.

Comment: Certainly, I have added them.

Comment: Check the equation $g_{ik}=\eta _{ab}e^a_ie^b_k$

Comment: Thank you so much, I found that the vierbein I gave does not satisfy the equation that you proposed. I have since changed the vierbein and even checked the second equation it must also satisfy, i.e. $\eta_{ab}=e^{\mu}_{a}e^{\nu}_{b}g_{\mu \nu}$, and found that the inverse vierbein, i.e. the inverse of the matrix e does indeed satisfy the equation.

Comment: OK! Now $\omega^a_{\mu \nu}$ are calculated correctly?

Comment: I would assume so? If I am not mistaken I have taken the sum over the appropriate indices above and taken the derivatives of the inverse vierbein as suggested by the equation. I believe I have followed the calculation correctly, yet the solutions still seem a bit long and off.

Comment: Check it on a metric with a known result.

Comment: Thank you so much that is a great idea.

Comment: quick question: how would I write the following function in Wolfram a(t), where a is a function of time and taking a derivative of time will not give a vanishing term, since when I try to write a(t)^(2), I get back a*t^2 which is not what I want, but rather a(t)^(2), i.e. the function a of t squared, also if I want to write sin(theta). Thank you so much

Comment: Use `[]` instead of `()`, for example `a[t]`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestion. Upon attempting the code on a metric with a known result, I don't seem to get the same responses. Could it perhaps be because I am not summing over the correct indices? I believe I followed the equation correctly. My concern is if Wolfram understands the difference between these matrices being [1,1]-tensors, or if that even matters. Thank you again

Comment: @AlexTrounev I have added a picture of the spin connection in order to make clearer what I am referring to, for easier reference rather. Thank you